# Equivalent norms on $C^1[a,b]$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I'm having a hard time (dis)proving these two norms are equivalent.

Let $\|f\|_1=\|f\|_{\infty}+\|f'\|_{\infty}$ and $\|f\|_2=\|f\|_{\infty}+\int_a^b|f'(x)|dx$ be two norms on $C^1[a,b]$. I need to prove or disprove that these two norms are equivalent.

First, I thought they weren't equivalent. I considered the sequence $f_n(x)=\sin(nx)$, then $f_n'(x)=n\cos(nx)$. Then $\|f\|_1\rightarrow\infty$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ and $\|f\|_2$ is bounded as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Am I correct?

I really find it difficult to find an intuitive feeling if two norms are equivalent. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: The approach is the correct one, but the example you picked is NOT a counterexample, as the norm 2* is also unbounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why, in your example, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f\|_2=+\infty$.

However, you can take $f_{n}(x)=\left(\frac{x-a}{b-a}\right)^n$. Then, yes, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f\|_1=+\infty$, whereas the sequence $\bigl(\|f_n\|_2\bigr)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is bounded.

Comment: Why isn't it clear that the norm (1) is unbounded? The $f'$ infinity norm is unbounded as $n$ goes to infinity

Comment: @b00nheT Sure. My mistake. I meant $\|\cdot\|_2$. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Indeed, I should have assumed it was a typo. Nice simple counterexample.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm going to work out the counterexample to see if I get it now.

Comment: @Caroline One suggestion: assume that $[a,b]=[0,1]$. Then $f_n(x)=x^n$.

Answer (score 0):

You can take
$$f_n(x) = \arctan\left(n(x-a)\right)$$
Then
$$\|f_n^\prime\|_{L^1} =\|f_n\|_\infty = \arctan\left(n(b-a)\right)
\to\frac{\pi}{2}\qquad \|f^\prime_n\|_\infty = n\to+\infty$$